# How to filter a data frame in R based on a vector of column names?

Tags: r

I have a vector of column names that I would like to use to filter the `mtcars` data frame:

```
columns <- c("gear", "carb", "cyl")
```

I have tried the following, but get error messages:

```
filt_df <- mtcars %>% filter(columns == "4")
Error: Result must have length 32, not 3

filt_df <- mtcars %>% filter_at(vars(columns) == "4")
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a logical vector
```

What is the correct syntax for getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do

```
cols <- c("gear", "carb", "cyl")
mtcars[rowSums(mtcars[cols] <= 4) == length(cols),]
```

-output

```
#                  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you're trying to do something like this (note I changed your predicate slightly, since none of the rows of `mtcars` have `gear == carb == cyl == 4`):

```r
library(dplyr)

columns <- c("gear", "carb", "cyl")

mtcars %>% filter(across(all_of(columns), ~ .x <= 4))
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```